# JsonDocument Parse JsonReaderException - xUnit

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I thought I found a cleaner way with a smaller footprint to test a `string` to see if its valid `JSON`; however when I run a test its failing because its returns a `JsonReaderException` so when I tried to change the type to this, I get a protection error as it seems to be internal??

I am using `System.Text.Json` in my project.

How can this be changed so I can use my existing code:

```
    public ApplicationSettings WithTemplate(string template) {

    try {
        JsonDocument.Parse(template);
        baseTemplate = template;
    }
    catch(JsonException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Test Code:

```
[Fact]
public void WithTemplate_ThrowsJsonExceptionWhenBaseTemplateIsInvalid() {
    Assert.Throws<JsonException>(() => new ApplicationSettings()
                                    .WithTemplate("345[]{}q345"));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that was just as compact as `JsonDocument.Parse()` for just checking the validity of string of `json` with the `JsonSerializer`.

```
string malformedJson = "345[]{}q345"

JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(malformedJson)
```

Then I was able to test against the exception `JsonException` and not have to worry about `JsonReaderException`